# Codeigniter how to delete value from database that not exist in post data

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Db tables:
id | user_id | skill_id 
1  |    3    |     1 
2  |    3     |    4

Situation: User click on button submit to post data to database->(Example) the data is user_id (3) and skill_id(1).

I want to compare with data in database, if the post data not exist in database for example the post data is user_id(3) and skill_id(1) then the data with id(2) will be delete.

The purpose of this is for checkbox function if user tick the checkbox the new data will be added to database. If user uncheck the checkbox the data will be deleted.

My current Code:

```
     $query = $this->partner_vs_skill_model->where('partner_id',$id )->get_all();
        $row = count($query);

        foreach ($query as $row) {
            foreach($skill as $value){
                //$s = $row->skill_tag;
                if($row['skill_id'] === $value){
                    break;
                }
                else{

                }

            }   
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the following: "the post data is user_id(3) and skill_id(1) then the data with id(2) will be delete"? why would 2 be deleted? and which id of 2? the user or the skill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you are overthinking here to much -

just delete your items at first, and insert it after,

the following should work (i assumed, that you have to have at least one skill in your array, but its totally up to you whether you want that or not..)

```
$userId = 3;

if (count($skill) > 0)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userId)->delete('your_table');

    foreach($skill AS $skillId)
    {
        $arrInsertData = [
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'skill_id' => $skillId
        ];
        $this->db->insert('your_table', $arrInsertData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes overthinking too much... this exactly the simple solution that i need thank you very mush